# Froala editor images absolute url path configuration

Tags: url, wysiwyg, froala

I was wondering if there's any option that after image upload the image source will be `<img src="/uploads/image.jpg" />` rather than `<img src="http://example.com/uploads/image.jpg" />`?

I can't find it anything about this and I have lots of content that it's added on localhost and when I upload it to production I'll have to manually change the links

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps can you try to find/replace when image inserted. Something like this :

```
$(".selector").on('editable.imageInserted', function (e, editor, img) {
var source = img.replace('www.host.com','');
$('.img_class').attr('src',source);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions as answered by the creator of froala https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/445

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is using Froala's [image server upload example](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/sdks/php/image-server-upload) and simply adding the domain at the beginning of the link

```
<?php
// Include the editor SDK.
require '/path/to/wysiwyg-editor-php-sdk-master/lib/FroalaEditor.php';

// Store the image.
try {
  $response = FroalaEditor_Image::upload('/path/to/upload/');
  $response->link = "https://www.example.com" . $response->link;
  echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  http_response_code(404);
}
?>
```